# Using Python for a Wacom tablet on Mac & Linux

Tags: python, macos, wacom

I am shortly going to buy a Wacom Bamboo Pen&Touch, and I'd like to be able to access it from Python, preferably using PyQt. I've found a Python module for accessing it under windows ([cgkit/wintab](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/wintab.html)) and I've seen Python code for accessing it using GTK ([GnomeTabletApps](http://www.alexmac.cc/tablet-apps/)).

Is there an equivalent for Mac? The [Cocoa documentation](http://www.wacomeng.com/mac/index.html) provided by Wacom is way beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PySide's QTabletEvent works on Mac. I have also used it on Ubuntu.
http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTabletEvent.html#PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent